# How to find not zero number in double array?

Tags: java, android

If I have a double array like this:

```
[0.0,12.0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,6.0,5.0,0.0]
```

and I would to calculate the average of only not 0.0 number, why this code not work fine?

```
public static double Average(double[] myarray) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        double dValue = 0.0;
        int counter=1;
        if (myarray== null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The array must be defined or diferent to null");
        }
        if (myarray.length == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The array must have size greater than zero");
        }
        for(int i = 0 ; i < myarray.length ; i++) {
            if(myarray[i] > 0.0){
                counter++;
                dValue += myarray[i]/counter;
            }
        }
        return dValue;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dividing with counter on each iteration which won't give you the average. You need to take the divide by the final counter number once you have the total sum.

Just do this:

```
public static double Average(double[] myarray) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    double dValue = 0.0;
    int counter=1;
    if (myarray== null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The array must be defined or diferent to null");
    }
    if (myarray.length == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The array must have size greater than zero");
    }
    for(int i = 0 ; i < myarray.length ; i++) {
        if(myarray[i] > 0.0){
            counter++;
            dValue += myarray[i];
        }
    }
    return dValue/counter;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Divide by `counter` after the loop, not in it.

Actually you would have to divide always by the final counter value minus one (not the incrementing value) which is not possible during the loop.

Comment: Do you mean out of "if" loop?

Comment: @DoctorWho The `for`-loop is meant, `if` doesn't define a loop

Answer (score 2):

Because you of this line

```
dValue += myarray[i]/counter;
```

you shoud make you loop

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < myarray.length ; i++) {
        if(myarray[i] > 0.0){
            counter++;
            dValue += myarray[i];
        }
}
dValue = dValue / counter;
```

Additinaly counter should be initialized with 0. So you should add a check before last line

```
if(counter == 0){
   // Handle Divide by Zero Exception
   return 0;
}

return dValue / counter;
```

This is accually pretty important since when for e.g. you array has 1 element you will return the value of this element divided by 2 not by 1

Answer (score 0):

The Reason is that your counter is incremented during the loop so your average is  always wrong because every number is  not divided on the same counter